# Sum of elements within an array in snowflake table

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with mulitple columns  , one is data type int and other is varchar containing array data , third is varchar , forth is varchar

Is there any way I can get the sum of the elements within this col2 array column ? while other row values remain the same

Ex : Input

```
| col1     | col2           |   col3 | col4    |
| -------- | -------------- |--------|---------|
| 2        | [2,3,4,]       |    5   |     7   |
| 2        | [3]            |        |     9   |
| 2        | [3,2]          |        |     9   |
```

Output

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 9 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 |  | 9 |
| 2 | 5 |  | 9 |

This table has billions of records so cost is also a consideration

I tried using the `array_agg(sum(col2))` but it didn't work

Comment: I believe that you would need to write your own function to do this - I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box SQL solution to this problem (though happy to be proved wrong). However, it would definitely be easier if your table columns had the correct datatypes for the data they are storing

Answer (score 0):

Using helper function:

```
create or replace function sumarray(arr array)
returns float
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'main'
as
$$
def main(arr):
  return sum(arr)
  # return sum(filter(lambda v: v is not None, arr))  # removing None 
$$;
```

and main query:

```
SELECT *, sumarray(TRY_PARSE_JSON(tab.col2)) AS col2
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNNEST equivalent [FLATTEN in snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten) to do this.

> The FLATTEN function can be used to transform an array of values in a
> table into multiple rows, where each row represents a single element
> from the array.

```
SELECT col1, SUM(t.element::int) AS col2, col3, col4
FROM your_table, TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => col2)) AS t
GROUP BY col1, col3, col4;
```

This shall give you the expected output :

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 9 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 |  | 9 |
| 2 | 5 |  | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to do this in pure SQL :) . There are probably more concise ways to write this but this shows the steps/logic I followed:

```
with t1 as (
     select 
     col1
    ,col2
    ,replace(replace(col2,'['),']') col2a
    ,col3
    ,col4
    from array_test
),
t2 as (
     SELECT * 
    ,case when ascii(value)=0 then '0' else value end value_a
    FROM t1, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t1.col2a, ',')
)
select
    col1
   ,sum(to_number(value_a)) col2
   ,col3
  ,col4
from t2
group by seq, col1, col3, col4
;
```

FYI (in case you are unaware) the columns "value" and "seq" are generated automatically by the LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE - along with some other columns.